# Rspec request spec examine response body

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec-rails

Since rspec 3.5 request specs are used to test controller behaviour plus route testing and the correct rendering of the view with the content.
The last part troubles me a bit since i do not understand the thin line of what goes in the view specs to what stays in the request specs.

On [relishapp](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/request-specs/request-spec) i found this piece:

> `expect(response.body).to include("Widget was successfully created.")`

which tempted me of including the following in my request test:

```
describe "Index page" do
  ....
  it 'includes a link to cars_parts' do
    get "/car_overview"      
    expect(response.body).to include("car_parts_path")
  end
  ....
end
```

This test fails.
In the view i use the `link_to` on the  `car_parts url_helper`.
The failing test dumps the whole response.body String and i see the `car_parts_path` but rspec does not see it. How do i have to change my test to make it pass without the use of capybara since it is only useable with feature specs now.
And am i doing it correct after all or should this kind of test go somewhere else?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think you might need to change the string to a method.

### Before

```rb
expect(response.body).to include("car_parts_path")
```

### After

```rb
expect(response.body).to include(car_parts_path) # Remove the quotes
```

### Explanation

`car_parts_path` is a method in Rails, which will evaluate to the actual path. If you're using that URL helper in your view this should work.

**But I thought the response body was a string?**

Yup, it is. When you call `car_parts_path`, you're calling a Ruby method in the Rails framework.

`car_parts_path` will **return** a string. This string will be `"/car_parts"`.

Basically, any time you see `car_parts_path`, imagine it's `"/car_parts"` as a string. Because the two are exactly equivalent.

**In the test**

So when you have this in the test:

```
expect(response.body).to include(car_parts_path) # car_parts_path is a method that returns "/car_parts" so it's the same as...
```

It's evaluates to the same as:

```
expect(response.body).to include("/car_parts")
```

**In the view**

In your ERB view you'll have:

```rb
<%= link_to "Car Parts", car_parts_path %>
```

This is evaluated to:

```rb
<%= link_to "Car Parts", "/car_parts" %>
```

This renders an `a` tag in your html:

```
<a href="/car_parts">Car Parts</a>
```

### Conclusion

You're checking for `"/car_parts"` in the response body and the view contains that string, the test now passes and you're all set!

**Why did my original code not work?**

Rails was looking for `"car_parts_path"` as a string - and the view doesn't contain that anywhere.

You were looking for the method name as a string rather than the string the method returns.

Any more questions, just ask!

Comment: Excellent that worked!. I thought since the response.body is of type String i only can look for Strings. There is very little in the rspec docs about the response.body and how to handle it. Do you have a link to some resource? Cheers!

Comment: I don't have a specific resource as I'm not quite sure what you're asking... I will say that you're exactly correct - the response.body is just a string. And yes, you can only check for strings within a string. I suspect your confusion comes from the difference between `car_parts_path` and `"car_parts_path"`. I'll update my answer.